# Can I add /something to URL with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let assume I'm on page www.example.com. Can I add /first to the URL so that it becomes www.example.com/first on click WITHOUT refreshing the page. I'm trying to do this after an AJAX request which changes the page, so that I could indicate the page has been changed.

For example:

```
$('.admin-categories').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : adminCategories,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        },
        success : function (data) {
            $(".admin-container").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Can I append /categories to the URL on success of this AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the History API in JavaScript and replaceState method specifically.

```
history.replaceState(null, null, 'first');
```

Here is a good resource about it:
https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api

Comment: Hmmm, while this does change the URL, it doesn't just append it but also replaces what I currently have. For example, I have www.domain.com/admin and instead of changing the URL to www.domain.com/admin/first, it changes it to www.domain.com/first.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why, but your link redirects me to something related to CSS

Comment: Fixed the link... and you can do the full path: history.replaceState(null, null, '/admin/first');